# How can i use jquery in my ios program?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios

I want to use jquery in my iphone program. Is it possible?

If so, anyone help me with some main steps: which files i have to import or something essential.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) in webviews, or a cross-platform SDK like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) which will create webviews for you.

Comment: Thanks. I want more explanation. The main steps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use jQuery on a remote URL within a UIWebView you can inject it using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`

Here are two methods for doing that, I opted for the second:

**1. Load jQuery remotely from googleapis.com**

Note: the `andJS:` parameter can be a vanilla JS backup in case jQuery doesn't load:

```
- (void)injectJQuery:(NSString *)jQuery andJS:(NSString *)js {
   // Load jQuery from googleapis.com
   NSString *jsString = @"function loadJQuery(e){try{if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'||typeof jQuery.ui=='undefined'){var t=10;var n=0;var r=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];var i=document.createElement('script');i.type='text/javascript';i.src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';r.appendChild(i);checkjQueryLoaded=setInterval(function(){if(t<n){window.clearInterval(checkjQueryLoaded)}n++},300);n=0;checkLoaded=setInterval(function(){if(typeof jQuery!='undefined'){window.clearInterval(checkLoaded);e(true)}else if(t<n){window.clearInterval(checkLoaded);e(false)}n++},500)}}catch(s){e(false)}}loadJQuery(function(e){if(e){__JQUERY__}else{__JS__}})";
   jsString = [jsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"__JQUERY__" withString:jQuery];
   jsString = [jsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"__JS__" withString:js];
   [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

The only drawback to this is that it takes a second before jQuery is loaded from Google. This wasn't acceptable for my situation so I used this instead:

**2. Load jQuery locally from your mainBundle (better solution I think)**

Create a new file called `jquery.js`; paste the contents of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) into it; make sure it's added into **Copy Bundle Resources** in **Build Phases**; then...

```
- (void)injectJQuery:(NSString *)jQuery {
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jquery" ofType:@"js"];
   NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:NULL];
   jsString = [jsString stringByAppendingString:jQuery];
   [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  You can use JQuery Mobile.  Consider your application and your application architecture and what it is you are trying to accomplish, before you get started.  If you want to create a "web application", written in HTML, JQuery/Javascript and CSS, that will be rendered inside the iPhone Safari browser, you can "wrap" your web application in a "native" iPhone application that can be downloaded and installed into the iPhone from the App Store.  Peruse the [JQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/) from your mobile device (iPhone) and view what options are possible.  I'd recommend starting with "Pages & Dialogs / Anatomy of a page", in the doc to get the "web application" started.  You can use PhoneGap to create the Objective-C, XCode app that will be submitted to Apple.  You can get started with Safari Development [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008134).